# Issue with Cordova 4.3.0 behind a corporate firewall

Tags: cordova, npm

We have an issue with Cordova when running it behind our corporate firewall & proxy.

Initially we thought the issue was related to the issue described here: http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/06/14/using-npm-behind-a-proxy/.

We discover that while npm could be fixed as described here this but did not fix Cordova.

We have configured npm to point at our Sona type repository but we discovered that Cordova does not pick up the ‘registry’ setting from npm as it has the registry hard coded in several places.
i.e.  In lazy_load.js

```
// Equivalent to a command like
// npm cache add cordova-android@3.5.0
// Returns a promise that resolves to directory containing the package.
function npm_cache_add(pkg) {
    var npm_cache_dir = path.join(util.libDirectory, 'npm_cache');
    // 'cache-min' is the time in seconds npm considers the files fresh and
    // does not ask the registry if it got a fresher version.
    var platformNpmConfig = {
        'cache-min': 3600*24,
        cache: npm_cache_dir,
 //OLD       registry: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
 //HACK
             registry: 'http://ourPrivateServer/nexus/content/repositories/npm-central/'
    };
```

Line #148 is the original line which we have had to modify with line #149.

This issue manifests when we do a “cordova platform add ios” for example.

We were wondering if any one else has encountered this problem and has a more eligant solution, as hacking the Cordova installation seems nasty?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the git configuration, and to change git to http protocol

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://www.yourproxy.com:port
$ git config --global https.proxy http://www.yourproxy.com:port

$ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

After these commands your .gitconfig file (normally un your user folder) gets filled with this content:

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[http]
    proxy = http://www.yourproxy.com:port
[https]
    proxy = http://www.yourproxy.com:port
```

Other proxy configurations that are recommended:

```
-- npm
$ npm config set proxy http://www.yourproxy.com:port
$ npm config set http-proxy http://www.yourproxy.com:port
$ npm config set https-proxy http://www.yourproxy.com:port

-- bower
$ set HTTP_PROXY=http://www.yourproxy.com:port
$ set HTTPS_PROXY=http://www.yourproxy.com:port
```